# How to make the diff tool in Visual Studio 2019 detect the changes made in tabulations (using Team Foundation Server)

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, diff, beyondcompare

I've just detected that Visual Studio does not seem to detect changes made in tabulations as a change in the diff tool:

For example, if I change the spaces used to tabulate a line to tab characters, the diff tool does not detect it as a change.

When using Beyond Compare instead, I see that this tool seems to do the job correctly, I mean, it detects those changes.

So the question is,... how to make the diff tool detect those changes ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The option moves around a bit depending on your version of Visual Studio, in 2019 it's here:

[image]

vs

[image]